# OpenCV, Nokia and Qt - Will it work?

Tags: qt, opencv, nokia

I was curious to know if someone had an experience of porting OpenCV to Nokia C5 series cell phones. Probably via Qt, is it possible to port OpenCV to Nokia, are there any know ports for OpenCV such as we have for Android and Apple iPhones.

Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [opencv-symbian](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencv-symbian/), but it's last update is 2010-07-12.

Nokia provides an alternative to OpenCV for the Symbian platform, it's named [**NCV**: Nokia Computer Vision library](http://www.allaboutsymbian.com/news/item/5618_Nokia_Research_Center_release_.php)

> The Nokia Research Center has released the Nokia Computer Vision Library (NCV). NCV builds on Symbian OS on S60 to provide additional imaging related functionality to developers for use in third party applications. The library includes motion sensing from the camera (for use in games), advanced image capture functions (algorithm constructions, panorama) and image post processing functions (morphing, image compositing).

Comment: is it powerful as OpenCV? Probably may not have the rich features of openCV, but must be good enough?

Comment: As powerful as OpenCV? I doubt it. [Here is a more detailed set of informational slides.](http://research.nokia.com/files/NokiaCVInformationalSlides.ppt). The [official NCV page](http://research.nokia.com/page/221) is full of broken links, that seems too amateur for Nokia.

Comment: Thanks. Going to have a peak at it. But I am already feeling its not worth a lot of time :)

Comment: Indeed, NVC is in v1.0 only. I think you might be better playing with opencv-symbian.

Comment: That is what I am exactly going to do.